# Simple XPath query issue

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm trying to find the titles of books that have more than 1 Author. 
I can find the titles of books priced over $20 shown below:

```
/bookstore/book[Price>20]/title
```

How would I find the titles of books with more than 2 authors?

with bookstore.xml being:

```
<bookstore>
<book>
<title> </title>
<author> </author>
<year> </year>
<price> </price>
</book>
</bookstore>
```

Comment: You would need to show the XML that corresponds to "more than 2 authors". Also, since this is a homework question, show your thought process so far. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

This work. Curious if faster:

```
/bookstore/book[author[2]]/title
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you simply would have multiple Author-Tags inside your book Tag the XPath expression would look like this:

```
/bookstore/book[count(author) > 1]/title
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but when I add '/title' it returns null. Where as if I didn't include '/title' it shows the authors that have worked together. Any ideas as to why this is returning null.